# Starting Android AVDs with snapshots through the command line

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

I have an Android virtual device with the snapshot feature enabled and a snapshot taken. When I start this AVD from Eclipse AVDManager, everything is fine: it resumes from the snapshot and then update the snapshot on exit.

However, I am unable to start this AVD (restoring the snapshot) through the command line.

According to the documentation, the command "emulator -avd AVDName" should automatically restore the default snapshot. But instead, I get the following error message:

PANIC: could not open: AVDName

Has anyone been able to launch a snapshoted AVD through the command line and restoring the snapshot.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure about the avd name?

Comment: @fasteque Yes, I double checked the AVD name. Plus, when the same AVD is not snapshoted, it starts without any problem using the same command.

Comment: Are you doing this from a command prompt with administrator access? Try doing it from a non-administrator command prompt.